# Как применить макрос в excel на всю таблицу

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

У меня есть макрос

```
Sub macros1()
Range("A2:C4").Find("1").Next = "lol"
End Sub
```

Он находит в табличке единицы и на соседней ячейке пишет lol
Но этот макрос работает только на 1 ячейку, а не для всех в таблице
Что делать?

Comment: *на соседней ячейке пишет lol* - Т.е. если `А2=1`, то в `В2` данные будут заменены на   `lol`? Опишите задачу точнее.

Comment: @vikttur совершенно верно

Comment: Что "совершенно верно"? Описать задачу точнее? Полностью согласен, описывайте :) Например, что делать, если и `А2=1`, и `В2=1` - затереть в `В2` без заполнения `С2`? А если  `С2=1` - в `D2` не записывать слово, т.к. ячейка уже не в диапазоне `A2:C4`?. Не стесняйтесь обрисовать задачу полностью.

Comment: @vikttur Таких случаев, когда например в ячейке А1 - 1, а в B1 что то есть, гарантированно нет. То есть соседняя клетка всегда пустая, и в нее можно записать слово lol.
Просто по таблице разбросанны значения, если в  ячейке 1, тов соседней должно появиться слово lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub macros1()
    Dim c As Range
    
    For Each c In Range("A2:C4")
        If c.Value = 1 Then c.Offset(, 1).Value = "lol"
    Next c
End Sub
```